# Paasing Array from MVC controller to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass an integer array from controller to jquery, so that i would be able to collect these values, and on the basis of these values, i'll check checkboxes in partial view.

How can i do this ?

my controller code is as follws:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult EditPartialView(string id)
{
    int selectedRoleId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    Role selectedRole = objRP.GetRoleByID(selectedRoleId);            

    Array RoleAccessMap = entities.RoleAccessMaps.Where(x => (x.Role_ID == selectedRole.Role_ID && x.Project_ID == selectedRole.Project_ID)).ToArray();
    int count = RoleAccessMap.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int? RAM_Id = ((AgileMVC_EL.RoleAccessMap[])(RoleAccessMap))[i].RAM_ID;
        int? item_id = ((AgileMVC_EL.RoleAccessMap[])(RoleAccessMap))[i].Item_ID;
        int? actionValue = ((AgileMVC_EL.RoleAccessMap[])(RoleAccessMap))[i].Action_Value;

        // i want to put code for javascript/jquery function here.
    }
    return PartialView("Edit", selectedRole);
}
```

I want to pass these values (RAM_ID, item_ID, actioValue) to jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use `Viewbag` as shown :

Just make a array from `for` loop(in controller action `'EditPartialView'`) and put that inside `Viewbag.data`.

In View retrieve `Viewbag.data` value in Jquery as :

```
var array = [];
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.data));
for(var i =0; i<array.length;i++){......}
```

Comment: @Mayank..i m saying that in controller action where you are looping through for loop there just make a simple one dimensional array and put it inside viewbag

Comment: i m not be able to understand as i m in dangerous state...  he he he...  so can u please display ur answer in a way u r trying to explain...  i have also given my controller code to you..  Plz

Answer (score 0):

You can use json object which is returned by your Controller

And call that controller by using [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with `dataType:'json'` option

Comment: i want to pass array from controller to jquery, not to controller from jquery,,,